# Facebook SDK 5.3 returning empty 'data' array in the body

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Using the following code:

```
$postId = "<userid>_<post_id>";

$this->facebook = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => $container->getParameter('facebook_client_id'),
    'app_secret' => $container->getParameter('facebook_client_secret'),
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$app = $this->facebook->getApp();

$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $app,
    '<access_token>',
    'GET',
    '/' . $postId . '/sharedposts?fields=from,via'
);

$response = $this->facebook->getClient()->sendRequest($request);

print_R($response); exit();
```

returns the following:

```
[body:protected] => {"data":[]}
[decodedBody:protected] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

But I can clearly see, within Facebook, that there is a comment, a share and a like on the post Id i'm querying

My end goal is to view how many times a post to FB has been shared by other FB users

Comment: Is it your post? Is it your page post? What kind of access token are you using?

Comment: It will only return posts that your app is allowed to see.